# Access Sitecore DB from API in Console application

Tags: database, console, sitecore

I would like to accesss the sitecore DB and items from console application like

Sitecore.Data.Database db = Sitecore.Context.Database
or
Sitecore.Data.Database db = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master")

how do I configure and setup my console application to access the DB as above?

Thanks Everyone for the suggestion, I am really interested in config changes, I used webservice, but it has very limited methods. For example, if I would like create an Item with the template and insert the item with prepopulated value, there is no such option. The reason I am looking for the console apporach is I would like to import the contents from XML or excel sheet and push those to the sitecore tree, eventually use the scheduled task to run the console app periodically. I do not want to copy the entire web.config and app_config. If anyone has already done this, could you please post your steps and necessary config changes?

Comment: You wont be able to do that. Why you want to do it? Maybe it is possible to point to you alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options I think:

1) Import the Sitecore bits of a website's web.config into your console application's app.config, so that the Sitecore API "just works"

I'm sure I read a blog post about this, but I can't find the reference right now. (I will have another look) But I think the simple but long winded approach is to copy all of the <sitecore/> element and all the separate files it references. I'm fairly sure you can whittle this down to a subset of the config required for data access with a bit of thinking.

2) Don't use the Sitecore API directly, connect to a web service that exposes access to it remotely.

There are a few of these that already exist. Sitecore itself exposes one, Sitecore Rocks has one, and Hedgehog TDS has one too. And you can always write your own (since any web service running inside the Sitecore ASP.Net app can make database calls and report values back and forth - just remember to consider security if this web service might end up exposed externally for any reason)

John West links to some relevant stuff here:

http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/09/Getting-Data-Out-of-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

-- Edited to add --

I've not found the blog post I remember. But I came across this SO thread:

[Accessing Sitecore API from a CLI tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621083/accessing-sitecore-api-from-a-cli-tool)

which refers to this blog post:

http://www.experimentsincode.com/?p=232

which I think gives the info you'll need for option 1.

(And it reminds me that, of course, when you copy the config stuff you have to copy the Sitecore binaries into your app's folder as well)

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to expand on @JermDavis' post and note that Sitecore isn't a big fan of being accessed when not in a web application. However, if you still want to do this, you will need to make sure that you have all of the necessary configuration settings from the web.config and App_Config of your site in your console application's app.config file.

Moreover, you will never be able to call `Sitecore.Context` in a console application, as the Sitecore Context sits on top of the `HttpContext` which means that it must be an application and have a valid request for you to use it. What you are looking for is something more along the lines of `Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master")`.

Good luck and happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for the Sitecore Item Web API. I use the Sitecore Item Web API whenever I need to access Sitecore data from the master database outside the context of the Content Management server or outside of the context of the Sitecore application. The Web API definitely does not allow you to do everything that the standard Sitecore API does but it can act as a good base and I now extend upon the Web API instead of writing my own custom web services whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JemDavis's advise. 
After I copied the  configuration and made changes to config section to get rid of conflicts. I copied almost all of Sitrecore, analytics and lucene dlls, it worked great. 
Only thing you have to remember is, copy the app_config folder to the same location where your dlls are. 
Thanks again JemDavis....